# execute killsession('7','281') error

Tags: linux, oracle, unix

**Here is my command:**

```
   set serveroutput on  execute killsession('7','281');
```

**Output:**

> ```
>  returns sh:syntax error: '(' is not expected
> ```

the execute kill session statement return this error.Why this is happening?the syntax is correct.

Comment: please be more specific. where did you try this? for what program are you using this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to execute a command that you should run inside `sqlplus`.

In your script, write something like that:

```
executeMe(){
    sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<EOF
        SET HEADING ON
        SET FEEDBACK OFF
        SET LINESIZE 3800
        SET TRIMSPOOL ON
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        SET SPACE 0
        SET PAGESIZE 0
    set serveroutput on  execute killsession('7','281');
    EOF
}

#do stuff
executeMe
#do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be an oracle statement that you need sqlplus to execute, not the unix shell. This isn't shell syntax.